# Codeigniter hour wise graph display

Tags: php, codeigniter, graph

[i want to display like this but below the time should come as i mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgDyh.png) hello below is my database result,i want to plot it in a bar graph using high chart in codeigniter in such a way that below it shows hour like 8-9 9-10 10-11 11-12 on above of this the orders done between these time has to display,please help [my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpKgd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far to reach your solution?

Comment: am just plotting graph based on the time and orders,but i need as i explained in the above

Comment: php itself won't be able to create bar graph unless you want it to generate an image. you'll need to use html, css, and most likely javascript. And to get the data you'll need to use PHP and pass it to javascript.

Comment: am getting everything,but i just need to display time like 8-9 9-10 etc above this the orders done between these timestamp has to display